# simple python script giving unexpected results

Tags: python, scripting

I have 250 curves in my scene and I need to apply the same extrude and bevel geometry to all the them.

I am running this script

```
import bpy
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    if obj.type == 'CURVE':
        obj.data.extrude = 0.005
        obj.data.bevel_depth = -0.002
        obj.data.bevel_resolution = 4
```

but when I run it it results in a bevel of "0.197" and a depth of "-0.787"
the bevel resolution works correctly.

Can anyone explain why this might be happening? Thanks!

[image: bevel example]

Comment: Look at the units. 0.005 m = 0.197 in, 0.002 m = 0.0787 in.

Comment: ok .. but when I type in 0.005 and .002 into the fields it looks fine. does the scripting only work in metric?

Comment: Lengths are stored in "Blender units". Multiply BUs by scene.unit_settings.scale_length to get meters. It will probably help if you just play around with the unit settings in the Scene Properties panel and see how that changes the displayed value.

Comment: @scurest consider making this an answer.

Comment: yeah. I did a inches to metric conversion and typed in those numbers and it worked perfectly. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am working in inches for this project and had to convert the numbers to meters. I had to use the following to get the desired amounts

```
import bpy
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    if obj.type == 'CURVE':
        obj.data.extrude = 0.000127
        obj.data.bevel_depth = -0.0000508
        obj.data.bevel_resolution = 4
```